# undefined method `default' for Chef::Resource::Template

Tags: templates, chef-infra, cookbook

I have created a template in chef, sending the value from attributes and recipes but getting error :

```
[2015-12-09T08:09:19-05:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2015-12-09T08:09:19-05:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-12-09T08:09:19-05:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2015-12-09T08:09:19-05:00] INFO: Sending resource update report (run-id: a9175420-0358-4631-8d30-664fdfd792c0)
[2015-12-09T08:09:19-05:00] ERROR: undefined method `default' for Chef::Resource::Template
[2015-12-09T08:09:19-05:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

How to resolve the error:

I have defined the attribute as :

default['abc']['LOG_FILE']=''

and in recipe it is

```
variables(


    :LOG_FILE => default['abc']['LOG_FILE'],
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong, you need to use node instead of default when referencing attributes:

```
variables(


    :LOG_FILE => node['abc']['LOG_FILE'],
```

Comment: This is right but you will get a linting error for ruby 2.0 + The new syntax is: `LOG_FILE: node['abd']['LOG_FILE']`